# How to split string by dots but leave parts wrapped with `` untouched

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a good way to split the string by dots, but don't touch the parts wrapped with a grave accent ("`"). I'm not sure if there is a regex to do it, so also the other approaches are welcome.

In other words, I'd like to convert this:

```
"a.`b.html`.c.`d.html`"
```

to this:

```
["a", "b.html", "c", "d.html"]
```

Comment: split by `"`"` then check if the string looks is `string.string` or `string.` or `.string.`. for the first example don't remove the dots, but do it for the rest

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: If there is no escaping then use: https://regex101.com/r/LyOtjY/1

Comment: @tnw what your comment brings to the discussion? And yes, I always try to find a solution before I ask...

Comment: So show what you've tried.

Comment: @tnw Posting my not working regexes won't add any value to the questions.

Comment: @akn Yes it would. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @tnw "Not all questions benefit from including code."

Comment: @akn Literally the next sentence: `But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some`. Are you just ignoring that AND all the down and close votes on this question?

Answer (score 1):

I would split by the ` character and then remove the leading and trailing dots. For this I'm using the [replaceAll method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
String input = "a.`b.html`.c.`d.html`";
String[] values = Arrays.stream(input.split("`"))  //split by the ` 
                                 .map(s -> s.replaceAll("(^\\.|\\.$)", "")) //remove dots
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                 .toArray(new String[0]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
```

Output:

> [a, b.html, c, d.html]

Comment: It doesn't work when the string doesn't contain any ```. I didn't mentioned it in my question, but that string can be also `"a.b.c.d"` and should be split properly too. Thanks anyway.